# Excel 2010 area chart drop off at the beginning

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-charts

Earlier this week, I asked a question about getting an area chart to drop off vertically instead of diagonally when I don't have enough data for some series.

https://superuser.com/questions/809955/excel-2010-area-chart-drop-off

teyley's answer works really well, that's exactly what I wanted. However, there is now some situations where I will have data for February to August for example but no data for January (because the employee wasn't yet in the enterprise at this moment for example).

It does create a diagonal drop off at the beginning of the chart again even though January's data are set to `NA()`. Using teyley's answer, I can get dynamic ranges for the series, but it still has to be progressive, the first row of data will always be January using that method. What to do if the data for a specific series actually starts on February?

So, assuming I have data for February to August, using teyley's example and answer, how could I make it so that there is a vertical drop off in February instead of a diagonal going down to 0 on January?

Here is the formula for the dynamic named range:

```
FirstSeries = OFFSET($B$1,1,0,COUNT($B:$B),1)
```

Then, I use this in the chart for each series as shown in my earlier question:

```
=SERIES($B$1,$A$2:$A:$A13,Book1!FirstSeries,1)
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you still need **Jan** showing on the graph, or can it start from **Feb** if **Jan** is missing

Comment: Yes, I definitely need the 12 months to be showing up in the chart even if there is data only for Feb to June.

Comment: @SeanCheshire That's probably what really makes this difficult, since I can already guess how to get it working without showing the unused first months.

Comment: Apart from drawing a blank square over the data, i can't think of anything... Let's see if any greater minds have any ideas

Comment: The blank square idea isn't that bad actually, I like it.

Comment: Problem is, the blank area isn't square... it's still a diagonal.

Comment: Could work if the blank series is made of bars with no separation lol. Not a really elegant solution but I guess it could work, problem is the bars are centered. I'm going to do some more tests in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from another forum, but I've been looking quite a while for the answer, so I'll post it here as well. The original thread can be found here:
http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1024240

- make your category axis into dates (not text or select automatically)
- insert a row in your excel sheet for the date where you want the cliff (move values down) and repeat that date. In your case your Date column will read: Jan, Feb, Feb, Mar, Apr, May etc, and you don't have to add any values in the cells that are created next to Feb in the One, Two, Three, and AxisSpacer columns.

I haven't researched how you can apply this with dynamic named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

As *Sean Cheshire* pointed out in the comments, one solution is to add white squares over the diagonal area at the beginning. There are probably multiple ways to do this. What I've done is creating a new series in the chart but instead of using areas, I'm using white bars with no shadows/borders and with no spacing. That said, there is another problem: the bars are centered on the X-axis. It means that the white bars will either cover half of a month or will be half a month short. To get around this problem, I added another series of white bars. That way, with 2 bar series, the bars aren't centered anymore, I just have to make sure to put the bars in the right place by putting the right numbers (0 or 1) in the white series.

It is not really elegant but it's still a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get a chart without a dropoff on the right (showing blank spaces), by using a "Placeholder" row that has a value of 0 across all columns.

1. Select the area you want on your table (notice, do NOT include empty/null cells)
   [image: Selected Data]
2. Create the Area Chart, using that selection, and click Select Data to modify some values. Click Edit to update the Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels, highlight your column headers again and click OK so you see them listed in the right panel, then uncheck the "blank series" in the left panel. You need to keep Placeholder checked to show your empty columns to the right of your data.
   [image: Changing Headers]
3. Finally, select and delete the Placeholder label in the legend, so it's as if it isn't there.
   [image: Finished chart]